# Treat null-terminator as regular character in C

Tags: c, arrays, null, cstring, null-terminated

I want to copy all the characters in a char[] to another char[]. However, suppose there are is a '\0' then I want to treat that as a normal character--a literal if you will. 
Therefore, when I printout the char[] with the format specifier %s, it should not stop in the middle. 
e.g.

```
// chars copied to array x
char x[] = {'h','e','\0','l','l','o','\0'}

printf("%s\n",x); // prints 'he\0llo'
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How should a string operator know if a nul character is terminating or not?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Why not just add your null terminus yourself since as a c string it's always required

Comment: @DoxyLover I make sure the indexing variable is not equal to length of the string - 1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to print the array element wise, translating non-printable characters to whatever you want to see instead.

To print out `he\0llo\0` do:

```
char x[] = {'h','e','\0','l','l','o','\0'};

for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(x); ++i)
{
  if ('\0' == x[i])
  {
    printf("%s", "\\0");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("%c", x[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: On a null character, you are printing two characters "\" and "0". Reading the OP's question, I believe he wants the actual null character sent to the terminal. The correction to your answer is to remove the if/then/first-printf/else (and braces) and just leave the second printf in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use `memcpy` if you know how many characters you need to copy. If `x` is a real array as in your example, `sizeof(x)` will give you that amount, but if you pass `x` as a parameter to a function, `sizeof` will not work inside that function (it will just show the size of the pointer), so the basic rule is that your strings either should be NUL-terminated, or you should keep their size in a separate variable.

For printing, you can either print in the `for` loop as @alk suggests, or use `fwrite` to write any buffer (possibly with NULs) to `stdout`:

```
fwrite(x, sizeof(x), 1, stdout); /* sizeof will work only for a real array */
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrong use of `"%s"`.  There is not a way to use `printf("%s"` to print an array with data after the first null character or `'\0'`.

```
char x[] = {'h','e','\0','l','l','o','\0'}
printf("%s\n",x);  // This only prints "he"
```

`printf("%s",...` is for printing strings.  `x` is a string only up to and including the first `'\0'`.

To "copy all the characters in a char[] to another char[].", use `memcpy()`.

```
char x[] = {'h','e','\0','l','l','o','\0'}
char y[sizeof x];

memcpy(y, x, sizeof x);
```

Code *could* use `"%c"` to print everything, but what gets printed with `'\0'` varies amongst systems.

```
size_t i;
for (i=0; i< sizeof x; i++) 
  printf("%c", x[i]);
```